# Opel Asta and Chevrolet Cruse VS Hyundai IX35 and Mitsubishi ASX

Tags: engine, hyundai, opel, reliability

Opel Astra and Chevrolet Cruse are both belong to GM and share same engine named Z18XER and F18D4. The engine was born in around 2007 and 10 years later it is still being installed on new cars. I put it on one site, and I'll call it Astra.

Hyundai IX35/Tucson  goes with engine G4KD known also known as 4B11 when it is sitting on Mitsubishi ASX. It is roughly 10 years and it is also still being installed on new cars. I put it on the other site, and I'll call it Tucson.

Which engine is more reliable and cheaper to service?

[Wikimotors](http://wikimotors.ru/) is taking audacity to compare them: [Tucson](http://wikimotors.ru/g4kd/) vs [Astra](http://wikimotors.ru/a18xer/), they say both are having rating 4, but the articles are in Russian. Do you know similar web resource but in English?

I don't agree with Wikimotors. I think Tucson is a way better. Do I overlook some Tucson problems that put it on the same shelf with Astra?

Comment: Google Translate works very well these days for common languages, such as Russian.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted another point of view.